# Errors with custom jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

I've been trying my hand at creating a custom slideshow from scratch using the Barrel guide "Building a jQuery Slideshow Plugin from Scratch" found here: http://www.barrelny.com/blog/building-a-jquery-slideshow-plugin-from-scratch/.  I've been following through step by step but decided to copy and paste the end result into fader.js.  The earlier non-optimized code was working correctly.

The page I'm having trouble with is located here: http://dataglyph.com/slidetest/

The errors that are showing up from FireBug are:

```
SyntaxError: missing formal parameter function animateSlides(active, new){
```

(with an arrow pointing at "new")

```
fader.js (line 49, col 35)
```

which points to this block of code in the file:

```
function animateSlides(active, new){
    if(fading || activeNdx == newNdx){
        return false;
    };
    fading = true;
    $pagers.removeClass('active').eq(newSlide).addClass('active');
    $slides.eq(active).css('z-index', 3);
    $slides.eq(new).css({
        'z-index': 2,
        'opacity': 1
    });
```

and the other error is:

```
ReferenceError: easyFader is not defined easyFader($('#Fader'),5000,800); /slidetest/ (line 15)
```

which points to where the slideshow is instantiated on my index page:

```
<script>
$(function(){
easyFader($('#Fader'),5000,800);
});
</script>
```

Can someone give me some insight as to why these errors are occurring?

Comment: Could it be that it's having issues because `new` is a javascript keyword?

Comment: That seems to be part of it.  I think the variable that should be there may be newNdx,  I'll post an answer when I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it turned out that new should be newNdx, but there were other issues besides that.  I should've used the codepen at the end of the tutorial which had code proven to work.